# How to obtain SUPER privileges on MySQL using AWS Instance as my connection?

Tags: python, mysql, admin, bulkinsert

I am trying to do a BULK insert on MySQL using python. I am also using an Amazon AWS Instance. This is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import datetime
from datetime import date
import random
from myfunctions import create_connection, execute_query, execute_read_query, connection


query = '''
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;
''' 
execute_query(connection, query)

query = '''
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\CIS3365\\CSV\\Student Info.csv'
INTO TABLE CIS3365.Students
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
'''
execute_query(connection, query)
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
The error '1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation' occurred
The error 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.' occurred
```

How do I obtain SUPER privilages?

Answer (score 1):

You need one of the rights mentioned in the error message. To grant one use a command like `GRANT SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN ON *.* TO 'user'@'%';` as database admin. Notice, this will grant rights globally and so is not suited for production.